# CodeIgniter activerecord, retrieve last insert id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Are there any options to get the last insert id of a new record in CodeIgniter?

```
$last_id = $this->db->insert('tablename',
    array('firstcolumn' => 'value',
    'secondcolumn' => 'value')
);
```

Considering the table consits of fields id (autoincrement) firstcolumn and secondcolumn.

This way you can use the insert id in the following code.

Comment: I keep come to this question for several times. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Shame on me...

I looked at the [user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id) and the first function is `$this->db->insert_id();`

This also works with activerecord inserts...

EDIT: I updated the link

Comment: the userguide is your best friend for things like this. i have been using codeigniter for 2+ years and i still find functions like this that i never knew about.

Comment: Be sure to wrap your insert and this function in a transaction as the query scheduler may insert another object before running this function

Comment: link is dead, updated link: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: I need to use insert_id(), but i don't know that insert_id() granted to get ID belong to insert() before it! I mean, Is it possible to retrieve ID belong another insert() in another request?

Answer (score 37):

Last insert id means you can get inserted auto increment id  by using this method in active record,

```
$this->db->insert_id() 
// it can be return insert id it is 
// similar to the mysql_insert_id in core PHP
```

You can refer this link you can find some more stuff.

[Information from executing a query](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html#information-from-executing-a-query)

Comment: link is not correct.please fix the link. new link http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 11):

for Specific table you cannot use $this->db->insert_id() . even the last insert happened long ago it can be fetched like this. may be wrong. but working well for me

```
     $this->db->select_max('{primary key}');
     $result= $this->db->get('{table}')->row_array();
     echo $result['{primary key}'];
```

Answer (score 8):

List of details which helps in requesting id and queries are

For fetching Last inserted Id :This will fetching the last records from the table

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Fetching SQL query add this after modal request

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

Answer (score 7):

After your insert query, use this command `$this->db->insert_id();` to return the last inserted id.

For example:

```
$this->db->insert('Your_tablename', $your_data);

$last_id =  $this->db->insert_id();

echo $last_id // assume that the last id from the table is 1, after the insert query this value will be 2.
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
public function insert_data_function($your_data)
{
    $this->db->insert("your_table",$your_data);
    $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $last_id;
}
```

Comment: @Dennis Decoene you may also visit this link https://ellislab.com/codeIgniter/user-guide.

Answer (score 6):

`$this->db->insert_id();`

Try this As your desired question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Returns the insert ID number when performing database inserts

[Query Helper Methods](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html?highlight=insert_id) for codeigniter-3

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

//please try this

Comment: This duplicate answer adds no new value to the page. It should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->db->insert('Your_tablename', $your_data)) {
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
return false
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter 3, you can do it as follow:

```
if($this->db->insert("table_name",$table_data)) {
    $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    return $inserted_id;
}
```

You may get help for Codeigniter 3 from here https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

In Codeigniter 4, you can get last inserted id as follow:

```
$builder = $db->table("your table name");
if($builder->insert($table_data)) {
    $inserted_id = $db->insertID();
    return $inserted_id;
}
```

You may get help for Codeigniter 4 from here https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/database/helpers.html