# how to get last insert id after insert query in codeigniter active record

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have an insert query (active record style) used to insert the form fields into a MySQL table. I want to get the last auto-incremented id for the insert operation as the return value of my query but I have some problems with it.

Inside the controller:

```
function add_post(){
    $post_data = array(
        'id'            => '',
        'user_id'   =>  '11330',
        'content'   =>  $this->input->post('poster_textarea'),
        'date_time' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'status'        =>  '1'
    );
    return $this->blog_model->add_post($post_data);
}
```

And inside model:

```
function add_post($post_data){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

I get nothing as the return of the add_post in model

Comment: For those who are wondering, `db->insert_id()` returns `false` after a `db->trans_complete()`. Make sure you get your `insert_id()`'s before you complete the transaction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter activerecord, retrieve last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985967/codeigniter-activerecord-retrieve-last-insert-id)

Comment: Anyone please mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Try this

```
function add_post($post_data){
   $this->db->insert('posts', $post_data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

   return  $insert_id;
}
```

In case of multiple inserts you could use

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: Unneeded use of transactions. @Crowlix's answer is more concise.

Comment: @Abraham what about concurrent inserts?

Comment: @ShekharJoshi afaik the insert_id() functions returns the id of the last insert performed by the db object you're using. This should handle concurrent inserts, shouldn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How does codeigniter know which rows were added by a particular object?

Comment: Why do we need to pass an id value to $insert_id variable? does CI3 can return any value if I return a function Ext: return $this->db->insert_id()?

Comment: what to do if my first column of table is not id and pk?

Comment: @ShekharJoshi It's not about objects, CI's insert_id() returns the last inserted id as per MySQL's [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), which keeps the last inserted id in a per-connection basis. Because of this, transactions are not needed for last inserted id's.

Answer (score 70):

A transaction isn't needed here, this should suffice:

```
function add_post($post_data) {
    $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: what about concurrent inserts?

Comment: @mander I believe insert_id() returns the id of the last insert performed by the db object it is called on. Even in the presence of concurrent inserts, wouldn't this mean it always returns the id corresponding to the insert this particular db object made?

Answer (score 29):

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 11):

From the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html#information-from-executing-a-query):

> #### $this->db->insert_id()
>
> The insert ID number when performing database inserts.

Therefore, you could use something like this:

```
$lastid = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Please don't give only a link but try to summarise the solution here

Answer (score 5):

Using the mysqli PHP driver, you can't get the insert_id after you commit.

The real solution is this:

```
function add_post($post_data){
  $this->db->trans_begin();
  $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);

  $item_id = $this->db->insert_id();

  if( $this->db->trans_status() === FALSE )
  {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return( 0 );
  }
  else
  {
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return( $item_id );
  }
}
```

Source for code structure: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually

Answer (score 2):

It is worth saying that the other answers relate to Codeigniter version 3. The answer in Version 4 (found https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html) is to use `$this->db->insertID()`

Answer (score 0):

because you have initiated the Transaction over the data insertion so,
The first check the transaction completed or not. once you start the transaction, it should be committed or rollback according to the status of the transaction;

```
function add_post($post_data){
  $this->db->trans_begin() 
  $this->db->insert('posts',$post_data);
  $this->db->trans_complete();
  if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    return 0;
  }else{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
}``
```

in the above, we have committed the data on the successful transaction even you get the timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete this topic:
If you set up your table with primary key and auto increment you can omit the process of manually incrementing the id.

Check out this example

```
if (!$CI->db->table_exists(db_prefix() . 'my_table_name')) {
    $CI->db->query('CREATE TABLE `' . db_prefix() . "my_table_name` (
  `serviceid` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=" . $CI->db->char_set . ';');
```

Now you can insert rows

```
$this->db->insert(db_prefix(). 'my_table_name', [
            'name'         => $data['name'],
            'hash'            => app_generate_hash(),
            'url'     => $data['url'],
            'datecreated'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'active'          => $data['active']
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Inside Model**
function add_info($data){
   $this->db->insert('tbl_user_info',$data);
   $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
   return  $last_id;
}

**Inside Controller**
public function save_user_record() {
  $insertId =  $this->welcome_model->save_user_info($data);
  echo $insertId->id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use `$lastId = $this->db->insert_id();`

Comment: buddy you can use above for get last insert id

Comment: duplicate answer