# PHP Codeigniter retrieve auto incremented ID from PHP MYSQL /PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently working on a school event system where each student has their own bar-code upon registration

I have a column `id` in my table which is auto incremented and to make my barcode unique I generated a random integer and I want that random integer to concatenate with the auto generated id.

I would like to know how am I going to get the value of the id upon registration to concatenate the random integer to their IDs

I would like to have an idea from you guys

Thanks a lot

Here is how I insert my data from the database:

[image]

The thing is, I want the `$temp` to concatenate to the latest id that is auto incremented

Comment: CodeIgniter last inserted id:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16440430/4248328

Answer (score 1):

You can get `last inserted auto increment id` by using the following method of `CodeIgniter`

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: @KyleCipriano can you share `updateAdvbarcode()` code?

Comment: @Hassaan just solved my problem thank you for your help

Comment: @KyleCipriano you can mark tick my answer if you found my answer useful :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
/*You should need to get last insert id after successfully registration
like this ex. */
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
/*after you need to concat id with randum value like this*/
/*function for randum value*/
$randvalue = rand(11111,99999);
$barcode =$randvalue.$id;
/*now you need to update value in db*/

mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE `table` SET `barcode`='".$barcode."' where (`id`='".$id."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would use `$this->db->insert_id()` which will return the last inserted id from the last query performed.

If you want an accurate answer, spend the time to include some code that you already have.