# How to get auto generated id after insertion?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I inserted records in database with auto generated id, now i want to get that id when i click on submit button that brings me multi file upload page

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440366/how-to-get-last-insert-id-after-insert-query-in-codeigniter-active-record)

Comment: `$this->db->insert_id()` is last inserted it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function add_post($post_data){
   $this->db->insert('posts', $post_data);
   $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();

   return  $insert_id;
}
```

In case of multiple inserts you could use

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Comment: use `$assignment_id=$this->db->insert_id();`  not `$this->db->assignment_id();`

Comment: I want to pass that id on other page using redirect, is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just insert this ‘id’ like a parameter

Comment: But better way to use session variables, if you work just in web development

Comment: did it like this: `redirect('Welcome/file_upload/assignment_id='.$res);` $res contains that auto generated id

Comment: I can not tell you for sure, post you controller, where you you call the method, and check the way how you making a redirection complying to codeignitor pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn->insert_id
```

will give you last insert id
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->insert_id();
```

This will give you last inserted id after inserting record.