# How to use the insert_id() with session to insert into other table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, insert

I am struggling whole day with this.

How do I use the `insert_id()` from my first insert into another function in my model?
I tried sessions, but I couldn't get it to work.

I tried everything.

My first insert looks like this:

```
    $aanbdata = array(
        'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
        'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
        'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
        'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie'),
        'prijssoort' => $this->input->post('prijsopties'),
    );      
    $this->db->insert('Aanbiedingen', $aanbdata);
```

I tried this:

```
    session_start();
    $this->session->set_userdata('aanbiedingid', $this->db->insert_id());
```

but my id runs 1 behind on the auto increment, so when I inserted a row with the id=4 then the session is id=3.

Why?

EDIT:

My model functions:

```
public function addaanbieding()
{
    $aanbdata = array(
        'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
        'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
        'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
        'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie'),
        'prijssoort' => $this->input->post('prijsopties'),
    );      
    $this->db->insert('Aanbiedingen', $aanbdata);

    $this->addimages($image_data, $this->db->insert_id());

    $catid = $this->input->post('categorie');   
    $bedrijfid = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');

    $bedrijfaanb = array(
    'idbedrijven' => $bedrijfid,
    'idaanbiedingen' => $this->session->userdata('aanbiedingid'),
    'idaanbiedingcat' => $catid
    );

    $this->db->insert('bedrijfaanbiedingen', $bedrijfaanb);

}

public function addimages($image_data)
{
    $insert_data = array(
        'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
    );
    $this->db->insert('fotoaanbiedingen', $insert_data);


    $fotoid = $this->db->insert_id();
    $aanbiedingid = $this->session->userdata('aanbiedingid'); //this does nto work

    $to_aanbiedingfotos = array(
        'idaanbiedingen' => $aanbiedingid,
        'idfotoaanbiedingen' => $fotoid
    );

    $this->db->insert('aanbiedingfotos', $to_aanbiedingfotos);
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use sessions for this?

Comment: Because I don't know another way. Maybe it's because I need to do something else, I'm busy with this all day.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985967/codeigniter-activerecord-retrieve-last-insert-id

Comment: @AnkitPokhrel read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

Controller:

```
$aanbdata['Aanbieding'] = $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam');
$aanbdata['Tekst'] = $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving');
$aanbdata['Prijs'] = $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs');
$aanbdata['Conditie'] = $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie');
$aanbdata['prijssoort'] = $this->input->post('prijsopties');

$last_id = $this->model_name->add($aanbdata); //change model_name with your model name
$this->session->set_userdata('name', $last_id);
```

Model:

```
function add($data) {
   $this->db->insert('Aanbiedingen', $data);
   return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: I've added my model, so you can look at it.

Comment: Man, you did a mass in code. But one think that I saw was this: $this->addimages($image_data, $this->db->insert_id()); HAS TWO PARAMETERS and public function addimages($image_data) HAS ONLY ONE.

Comment: I struggled with this too much yesterday, I fixed it now by returning the id to the controller. Thanks :)

Comment: New day is better for coding. Thanks for choose answer and voteup. Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Give the insert_id as a parameter to your model function.

Seriously, this is a very stupid answer. But I really don't know how to help you otherwise.
What's keeping you from calling the "other model function" directly after you made the insert?

Like

```
$aanbdata = array(
    'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
    'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
    'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
    'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie'),
    'prijssoort' => $this->input->post('prijsopties'),
);      
$this->db->insert('Aanbiedingen', $aanbdata);
$this->the_other_model->the_other_function($this->db->insert_id());
```

Comment: How do I call the insert_id in the other model function?, because there's another insert statement

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The other model has nothing to do with the insert from this model, so why should you call 'insert_id()' in the other model?`

And since 'insert_id()' gives you back the last inserted id, you somewhat have to immediately call it right after the insert().

Comment: Not another model. Another FUNCTION in my model. I will add both to my question so it's clear.

Comment: just look at my question :)

Comment: that really doesn't change anything. There is no reason to call 'insert_id()' in the other function. Just give it the return value if 'insert_id()' as a parameter.

Comment: I need the id from the first function to insert into the second. So how do I do that?

Comment: well, how about returning it?

in function addimages, after `$this->db->insert('aanbiedingfotos', $to_aanbiedingfotos);` add `return $this->db->insert_id();`

and in function `addaanbieding` you'd have

`$aabindig_id = $this->addimages($image_data, $this->db->insert_id());`

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't this in the wrong way? I need the id from addaanbieding in addimages.

Comment: Dude, no idea. You keep calling your function 'the other', 'the seconde' etc. and I do my best to guess, but it's really hard with function names in another language ^^

Comment: Sorry for that. I was really tired yesterday, so that's because of the annoying function names.