# how to retrieve id of record that is inserted by MySQL event

Tags: php, mysql, scheduled-tasks

Following is my code:

```
$schedule = $this->db->query("CREATE EVENT ".$data['id']." ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 1 MONTH ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO INSERT INTO oops_invoice 
(id, prefix, number, bill, account_id, order_delivery_id, date, staff_id, 
customer_note, recurrence, status, itp, utp) VALUES ('', '".$data['prefix']."', 
'".$data['number']."', '".$data['bill']."', '".$data['account_id']."', NULL, 
'".$data['date']."', NULL, '".$data['customer_note']."', '".$data['recurrence']."', 
'Draft', '".$data['itp']."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

$this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");
```

I stuck with id that how to retrieve id od row inserted by MySQL event..

i have tried following but does not worked when table is empty...

following code works fine except one case when table is empty....at that time it return nothing so i have been stuck...

this one is not same as we insert simple data this one inserted using MySQL event so **`$this->db->insert_id();` does not working**......

```
$last = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) AS `maxid` FROM `oops_invoice`')->row()->maxid;
```

Comment: don't focus on ternary operator that is not an issue

Comment: Well, describe the issue. "Does not work" is a little unspecific.

Comment: is that mysql or mysqli?? or pdo???

Comment: Why do you need the ID of the inserted row if the table is empty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter activerecord, retrieve last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985967/codeigniter-activerecord-retrieve-last-insert-id)

Comment: oh man $this->db->insert_id(); does not working because data is inserted by MySQL event

Comment: @TiiJ7 i want it after inserting data using event creation and $this->db->insert_id(); does not working in that case.....

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara: Is the `id` column an auto_increment field?

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara: When no data found and if you want to return any default you can try with `coalesce( max( id ), your_default_value_here )`

Comment: @Ravinder there is data inserted when event created but does not return id using function may be inserted after complition of execution so question is that is mysql event inserts data at that time or after that...??  if after then how to insert at creation of it

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara: Insertion occurs when `event` is being executed but not at the time of event creation. You can also include `starts` clause for `event`. Example: `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:55:00')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No requirement of retrieving id,
You can start event before 1 or 2 minutes of it's creation like this...
it will eliminate 2 insertion in table.

```
CREATE EVENT ".$data['id']." ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH STARTS DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL '0:01' HOUR_MINUTE) ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO INSERT INTO oops_invoice (id, prefix, number, bill, account_id, order_delivery_id, date, staff_id, customer_note, recurrence, status, itp, utp) VALUES ('', '".$data['prefix']."', '".$data['number']."', '".$data['bill']."', '".$data['account_id']."', NULL, '".$data['date']."', NULL, '".$data['customer_note']."', '".$data['recurrence']."', 'Draft', '".$data['itp']."', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    $this->db->query("SET GLOBAL event_scheduler =  'ON'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->lastInsertId()
```

must be your solution

Comment: Don't you try to get the last id of a creation event in your database ?