# Get row id from multiple query without using transactions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm creating social network site and И have wall where user post will be fetched.  When user create new post they have options to attach photos.
Post and attachment have diferent database tables and diferent Controllers and Models.

Problem is when i execute query for insert new *post* И need one more query for attachment witch will hold post_id. So first I need insert post in database then И need to insert attachments for that post? But how to get id for that post when all query is executed in some time?

Lets see my tables:

**Post**

```
post_id  account_id  post_text       
-------  ----------  -----------------------
1          1         Hello world post
```

**Attachments**

```
attachment_id  post_id  attachment_type  attachment_name  
-------------  -------  ---------------  -----------------
1              1          3               photo_1.jpg
2              1          2               video_1.mp4
3              1          3               photo_2.jpg
```

I dont want use transactions for this.

On submit I need to insert :

```
INSERT INTO post bla bla bla
INSERT INTO attachments bla bla bla <post_id> //how to get it when is executed in some time?
```

Comment: here is simple example of get `last insert id` : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Comment: I try with that. Is not that a little bad way because it is a large amount of information and some 12,000 profiles?

Comment: Please show your code? as you mentioned in two lines is not clear.

Comment: $this->db->insert_id();

Comment: I only have crud i need logic for controler how to get that id from post and insert it.

Comment: Let me try with `insert_id();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter activerecord, retrieve last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985967/codeigniter-activerecord-retrieve-last-insert-id)

Comment: You don't want to use transactions? Why exactly?

Comment: bcs am limited with databases

Answer (score 2):

If you are using codeigniter there must be some option to get the inserted id i used in this way before......

```
$this->db->insert('posts', $post_data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: Yes this work good. But what if i dont have attachment? Am getting all time new attachment row whith last id

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the last inserted id from `post` table and then `insert` into `attachments` table with reference id

```
INSERT INTO post (<FIELDS>) VALUES (<VALUES)

$pdo->insert('posts', $yourData);
$lastInsertId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Then you have to insert into `attachments`

```
INSERT INTO attachments (<FIELDS>) VALUES (<VALUES)
```