# How to get/return last inserted id in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have question. I have 2 tabel, name is 'tbl_pendidikan' and 'tbl_datapribadi'. And i have Model, name is **M_pascasarjana.php**

```
function pendidikan($table,$data) {
  $this->db->select_max('id_pendaftar');
  $get_id = $this->db->get('tbl_datapribadi');
  $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);

} //END FUNCTION//
```

This is my controller

```
foreach($_POST['user'] as $user) {
    $this->m_pascasarjana->pendidikan('tbl_pendidikan', $user);
  }
```

I try to get last id from table '**tbl_datapribadi**'. How to insert last id to table 'tbl_pendidikan'?

Comment: Try with `return $this->db->insert_id()`

Comment: Where i write?? Can you write for me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter activerecord, retrieve last insert id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985967/codeigniter-activerecord-retrieve-last-insert-id)

Answer (score 4):

```
function pendidikan($table,$data) {
    $last_row = $this->db->select('id_pendaftar')->order_by('id_pendaftar',"desc")->limit(1)->get('tbl_datapribadi')->row()->id_pendaftar;
    $data['column_name'] = $last_row;
    $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

$last_row will hold the last id present in `tbl_datapribadi` table. `column_name` will be your column name for last inserted id.

Comment: @syaifulhusein great.. you can upvote and accept my answer if it is helpful for you.. :)